# Use html elements as legend in react-chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs

I am learning react-chartjs. Till now I learn various concepts of react-chartjs. I am stuck on a problem: how can I make a custom legend in chartjs so that I have complete control over it? I go through multiple Stack Overflow questions regarding the same. I also googled about this topic but not getting any satisfied answered to the problem.

Here is my react-component code. I want two li item which behaves the same as the legend. I copy code from a Stack Overflow question but it didn't work.

```
import React from 'react';

import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
const recovery={
    labels:['Feb 15','Feb 16','Feb 17','Feb 18','Feb 19','Feb 20','Feb 21','Feb 22','Feb 23','Feb 24','Feb 25',
            'Feb 26','Feb 27','Feb 28','Feb 29','Mar 1','Mar 2','Mar 3','Mar 4','Mar 5','Mar 6','Mar 7','Mar 8',
             'Mar 9','Mar 10','Mar 11','Mar 12','Mar 13','Mar 14','Mar 15','Mar 16','Mar 17','Mar 18','Mar 19','Mar 20',
            'Mar 21','Mar 22','Mar 23','Mar 24','Mar 25'],
    datasets:[
        {
            label:'Corona Patients Recover and New Case DaiLy Basis In India',
            backgroundColor:'green',
            borderColor:'#333',
            borderWidth:2,
            data:[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,7,29,30,31,34,40,47,62,74,82,100,114,129,143,169,194,249,
                332,396,499,536,657]
        },
        {
            label:"Corona Death",
            backgroundColor:"red",
            borderColor:'#333',
            borderWidth:2,
            lineTension:0.1,
            fill:true,
            data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,
               4,5,5,7,10,10,12]

            }
    ]

}

class CoronaRecovery extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state={}
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <Bar 
                data={recovery}
                options={{
                    title:{
                        text:'Corona Patient Recovery',
                        display:true,
                        fontSize:20
                    },
                    legend:{
                        display:false,
                        legendCallback: function(chart) {
                            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
                            var borderColor = recovery.data.datasets[0].borderColor;
                            recovery.data.labels.forEach(function(label, index) {
                               ul.innerHTML += `
                                   <li>
                                      <span style="background-color: ${borderColor[index]}"></span>
                                     ${label}
                                  </li>
                               `; // ^ ES6 Template String
                            });
                            return ul.outerHTML;
                         }
                    }
                }}
                />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CoronaRecovery;
```

Comment: what is the expected and actual outcome?

Comment: expected output would be two li elements acting like a legend.i.e when I click on li elements graph changes accordingly.